# Tornado: Redirecting users after session ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, redirect, tornado

I have created a handler which handles the flow of the application based on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("current_user").decode('utf-8') if self.get_secure_cookie("current_user") is not None else None



    def prepare(self):
        if self.get_current_user() is None:
            print('not logged in')
            self.redirect('/login')
        else:
            print("Logged in user ",self.get_current_user())
```

This handler is then imported inside this handler which handles my login flow:

```
class TickLoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        try:
            user_name = self.get_current_user() if self.get_current_user() is not None else None
            if user_name is not None:
                self.redirect('index')
            else:
                print('inside login')
                self.render('login.html')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception in login get function:',e)
```

The `TickLoginHandler` is mapped to the `/login` endpoint and is responsible for redirecting the user back to the login page if the session ends or if the user tries to access any page inside the application if the user is logged out.

However, if the session ends and the user tries to visit any page in the application while logged out, the user is not redirected to the login page. Instead, the redirection returns the 304 HTTP code.

How could I make the user redirect to the login page if the currently logged in user's session expires while the user is inside our application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance to add redirection feature to each of your handlers:

```
class RedirectToLoginHangler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        if self.get_current_user() is None:
            print('not logged in')
            self.redirect('/login')
        else:
            print("Logged in user ",self.get_current_user())

class IndexPageHandler(RedirectToLoginHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        # extend the method but still invoke the parent's method to use login redirection
        super(RedirectToLoginHandler, self).prepare()
        # more code, extending prepare() for this handler

    def get(self):
        # whatever

class ContentPageHandler(RedirectToLoginHandler):  # in this handler we don't override prepare() so parent's method with redirection would be used
    def get(self):
        # whatever

class LoginHandler(RedirectToLoginHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        pass  # to avoid endless redirection override parent's method and do nothing
```